# C++ Identifier "_var" is undefined

Tags: c++, undefined, identifier

I am attempting to learn C++ (currently only know PHP and some C#) and have run into my first issue.

I am trying to call a class inside a switch, then use that defined variable after the switch. However, I get the error described in the title.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Hero {
protected:
    int hHealth,hStamina,hExp;
    string hName;
public:
    void Create(string);
    string GetName() {
        return this->hName;
    }
};

class Wizard:public Hero {
public:
    void SetStats(string hName) {
        this->hName = hName;

        this->hHealth = 40;
        this->hStamina = 80;
    }

};

int main() {
    string hName;
    int hClass;


    cout << "Welcome to Ryan's Dungeons & Dragons Adventure!\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your Heroes name\n";
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> hName;

    cout << hName << ", please select your class\n";
    cout << "(1) The Wizard\n";
    cout << "(2) The Warrior\n";
    cout << "(3) The Rogue\n";
    cout << "(4) The Priest\n";

    cout << "Class: ";
    cin >> hClass;

    switch (hClass) {
    case 1:
        Wizard _hero;
        break;
    }

    cout << _hero->GetName();


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The error in question occurs on the line:

cout << _hero->getName();

where it says _hero is undefind.

Comment: What you want is a factory that returns a smart pointer of your "CharacterClass"/Hero base class. When given 1 (or whatever you use to indicate "Wizard"), the factory returns an instance of the Wizard class.  And give this base class a virtual destructor.

Comment: It would be really cool if C++ allowed that... Would save so much headache ... Sometimes, the strict type safity of C++ is a pain. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_hero` is defined only within the scope of that `switch` statement. You need to create objects in the same or higher up scope that you'll be using them.

One way you can get around this is define a pointer to Hero before the `switch` (initializing to `null`) and then set it to a value inside the `switch`. For instance:

```
Wizard *_hero = NULL;
switch (hClass) {
    case 1:
        _hero = new Wizard();
        break;
    }
}

if (_hero) {
    cout << _hero->GetName();
}
```

You're also using the `->` on a class value (as opposed to a pointer to one). Scope issues aside, you probably intended to write `_hero.GetName()`. Inside your class, `->` is right however since `this` is a pointer to your object.

Comment: Because you need to create a reference to the class before creating the actual class inside a different scope. You can only achieve this with a pointer. (References must be initialized and can't be changed)

Comment: yan, thank you! that got rid of the error. I switched it to _hero.GetName and it gave me an "Error: expression must have class type" on _hero, so I kept it at ->, is that acceptable or should I look into the cause of the error when using .?

Comment: That's acceptable on the solution I provided, since I'm using a pointer type, not a value type.

Comment: -1 for suggesting dynamic allocation but not explaining the fact that the dynamically allocated object needs to be cleaned up somehow (e.g. using an `auto_ptr`).

Answer (score 3):

```
switch (hClass) {
    case 1:
        Wizard _hero;
        break;
} // <-- _hero is deallocated at this point

cout << _hero->GetName();
```

The scope of `_hero` is limited to the switch statement.

Comment: You mean to the switch statement.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to, or should I try a different method?

Comment: @Xeo - Yes, you are correct. In case of switch case **fall-through**, it should be able to be used. How ever, think of situation where `case 2` is a match and instance is being used in it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that even works in C#... what you want is a pointer that's going to be initialized in the switch statement:

```
Hero* _hero = 0;

switch(hClass){
  case 1: _hero = new Wizard;
  break;
}

// use _hero ...

// at the end, delete it
delete _hero;
```

Though, you now most likely need a virtual destructor and virtual functions. Read up on them, they're a powerful OO feature. But you probably know about them from C#.

Answer (score 1):

You said you know some C# and php, which I do not. I just want to know how would this have behaved in C#.

Creating an object inside some scope and using it outside the scope. Like: `{int a;} a = 0`;

In C++ its an issue.

```
    switch (hClass) {
    case 1:
        Wizard _hero;
        break;
    }
//At this no _hero is present. _hero is out of its scope
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_hero` object is restricted to the scope of that `switch` block. What you want is probably this:

```
Hero* _hero;

switch (hClass) {
case 1:
    _hero = new Wizard();
    break;
}

cout << _hero->GetName();
```

Comment: When I tried this, the error disappears however when I try to debug it, I get an error about unresolved externals

Comment: @Morgan: Well, I have no idea what that means. Did you type in "1" as input (just making sure)?

Comment: Doesn't even get to that point. Hit F5 to debug and it stops with that error. Will check Google and see if I find anything

Comment: @Morgan: If you initialize it to NULL as in `Hero* _hero = NULL` does that fix the problem?

Comment: Nope. Still the same error -- error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Hero::Create(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?Create@Hero@@UAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

Comment: Actually it looks like it's tied to a function I'm calling after the switch statement

Comment: -1 for suggesting dynamic allocation and not mentioning lifetime management or cleanup.

Comment: "Everyone else was wrong so my wrong answer is okay" is a bad attitutde to have.  That said, you may notice that I downvoted the one other answer that recommended dynamic allocation but failed to explain the consequences of doing so.

Comment: @James McNellis: Not when I said that, anyways. That's not the attitude I was taking - I was just wondering.